# BLE : Host stack - HCI - Controller

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, usb-hostcontroller

I am new to BLE/Bluetooth programmming. As known,BLE/Bluetooth is an entire module.Recently I found that, the NimBLE provides the Host Stack or Controller part of Bluetooth.https://github.com/apache/mynewt-core . Here they mention that it supports the mix and match of any host stack with any controller.

1. So, is it that the HCI layer(through which the host stack interacts) and the Controller (lower bluetooth layer)   implementation of all the modules same or is it vendor specific?
2. If I choosse a host stack from the NimBLE, does the implementation of HCI allow me to operate with any vendor's controller or is that the HCI layer should be implemented with vendor specifications and dependent on the controller.

I assumed that the controller part of the Bluetooth /BLE module has the basic RF and communication section,which will be the same for all modules for its interoperability. I am sorry if the question is trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any host stack with a hci interface should work with any hci controller, as long as they both have support for the same transport method (UART, USB etc.)

Sometimes, in particular for usb you also need a specific  host driver that opens up the transport interface for the particular device. For UART some vendors requires some vendor specific setup packets being sent over UART that configures baud rate etc before hci can start.

Also the host and controller should have a common feature set. For example you can't do much with a host that only supports Bluetooth classic and a controller that only supports BLE.

Some hci controllers implement custom vendor commands to offer extra features over the standard commands, such as for example set custom public Bluetooth device address. A host must also support these commands in order to make use of them.

Comment: As per your first statement my question 1 is not really vendor specific(should be true for other communication methods like SPI,IIC) , but it seems that the Controller has the _possibility_ of having vendor spec commands in lower level .Hence , there can be a generic HCI layer but not for _every controller_ though it supports the same communication method. Did I get it right?

Comment: Yes the controller has the possibility to have vendor specific commands, although none of them are of course not required for a standard implementation. If we take UART for example, if you have two controllers (running at the same baud rate) you can use either of them without the need to change the host side.

Comment: okay,it cleared up my mind. Thanks! @Emil If I implement these types of Host stacks with HCI layer (from vendors)on my µc and make some custom modifications in the stack , For eg: I use one of the BLE stack profile to receive image or data, to access any BLE controller(something like a generic stack to access any controller for standard implementation),is it mandatory to get any certification ?

Comment: I don't know. You could ask Bluetooth SIG through their portal.

Comment: @kaya For your query of "is it mandatory to get any certification ? "

 Host and controller certification are done separately. If you want to monetize your solution, having it certified helps as it is a proof that your solution adheres to SIG recommended specification and can interest probable users/ customers to use your solution.